# How to delete multiple type of files?

Tags: linux

I can delete .zip files using following command.

```
find . -type f  -name '*.log.*.zip' -exec rm \{\} \;
```

Is it possible to delete .zip and .gz file at the same time ?

```
find . -type f  -name '*.log.*.zip' | '*.log.*.gz' -exec rm \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
$ rm -rf log.{zip,gz}
```